# Her vs she in the given construction

Tags: pronouns

Which of these two sentences is grammatically correct?

We were both lying on the bed, **her** in my arms.

We were both lying on the bed, **she** in my arms.

Comment: *She* was in your arms. *Her* body was in your arms.

Comment: I was cuddling her on the bed. :)

Comment: We were both lying **in** (under the covers) bed, **as I held** her in my arms ...

Comment: We were both lying on (on= on top of) the  bed, she **was** in my arms...

Answer (score 1):

> You, lekon, were lying on the bed, her in your arms.
>
> You two were lying on the bed, she in your arms.

I think you'd decide which case to use in the absolute adjunct (she vs her) based on whether she is included in the subject of the verb in the main clause, or  not.